# Django Pinax-Project-Account github setup

Tags: python, django

So I am fairly new to Github and Django for that matter, I was digging around for a template of a website using Django offering user authentication and cam across this

[pinax-project-account](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account)

I setup django and python for use within my cmd and using a virtual env and I stepped through the setup list but I'm stuck using:
`chmod +x manage.py`

I understand this is for use in Unix just wondering how I get the same desired function in windows? as if I skip this step it won't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that, as Windows has no executable bit. Instead of running

```
./manage.py whatever
```

just run

```
python manage.py whatever
```

making sure that `python.exe` is on your `PATH`.

Comment: Yeah i understand that just confused about a work around for chmod +x when your not using Unix

Comment: @Nebbyyy it's because they failed to include it in their `requirements.txt` - it's not your fault. Open an [issue](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/issues/new) and explain in detail what you've done, including the full text of the error you get. Tell them they either need to include [`django-bootstrap-form`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-bootstrap-form) in their requirements, or drop it from `settings.py`.

Comment: @Nebbyyy you deleted your original comment as I was replying to that - why? In regards to your second comment, there **is** no workaround for using `chmod +x` in Windows - the command doesn't exist, because it is meaningless in a Windows context. `chmod +x` sets the executable bit of a file, so you can run it without invoking the name of its interpreter or whatever. Since Windows **has** no executable bit, the command doesn't mean anything, and can be omitted. You'll just need to run `manage.py` by calling `python` first.